# jquery ui autocomplete with categories displayed horizontally, not vertically

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

is their an existing plug-in, or code to do that enables the categories to be dispaled horizaontally, like table headers :

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories

Or is it easier to just start my own from scratch ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this problem?

Comment: @damd I started to write my own jquery plugin, but have not really got very far. Keep meaning to go back to it.

Comment: I'm working on the exact same thing right now. I think I've gotten a bit on the way now. I'll let you know if I come up with something you could use.

Comment: @damd is your project on github or similar ... I could help out.

Comment: I'm afraid not and I can't really do that for various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You most probably have a conflicting css somewhere.

I encoutered this issue and solved it last week.

The code that was conflicting (for me) was this one:

ul { list-style: none; }

This most probably is included in your style.css file or inside your web page somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

https://codepen.io/nitinmendiratta/pen/aMMeOz

CSS

```
#search {
  width: 500px;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  display: flex;
  width: auto !important;
}

.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.ui-autocomplete-category ul{
  padding:0;
}
.submenu {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* ADDED STYLE */
.ui-autocomplete>li>div>ul{
  display: block !important;
  position: relative !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
span.ui-menu-icon{
  display:none !important;
}

/* ADDED for the SO snippet only !! Not needed on CodePen */
.ui-autocomplete>li{
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
  },
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      var li, submenuUl;
      if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        var elt = $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
        var submenu = $("<div class='submenu "+ item.category +"'><ul></ul></div>");  // Added <ul></ul>
        elt.append(submenu);
        ul.append(elt);
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      submenuUl = ul.find("."+item.category+" ul"); // added +" ul"
      li = that._renderItemData(submenuUl, item );
      if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label ).addClass("ui-menu-item"); // Added the addClass()
      }
    });
  }
});


// Actual Code
$(function() {
  var data = [
    { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
    { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
    { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
    { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
    { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
    { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
  ];

  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(item, ui){ // Added item, ui --- Arguments were missing.
      console.log(ui.item.value);
      $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.value );
     $( "<div>" ).text( JSON.stringify(ui.item) ).prependTo( "#log" );
      return false;
    }
  });   
});
```